# Is there a way to write to the windows event log in C?

Tags: c, windows, event-log

I have a requirement to modify a simple windows service written in win32 C (not c++).

Is there a library I can use to write event log entries to the windows event log without using eventcreate.exe? Or do I have to modify it to be compiled as a c++ program?

Comment: For doing this programmatically, you might want to start from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd996928(v=vs.85).aspx).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, see the function [ReportEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363679%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and its [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363680%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

The event provider source file with .mc extension looks like this:

```
; // MyEventProvider.mc 
; // This is the header section.
   SeverityNames=(Success=0x0:STATUS_SEVERITY_SUCCESS
               Informational=0x1:STATUS_SEVERITY_INFORMATIONAL
               Warning=0x2:STATUS_SEVERITY_WARNING
               Error=0x3:STATUS_SEVERITY_ERROR
              )
   FacilityNames=(System=0x0:FACILITY_SYSTEM
               Runtime=0x2:FACILITY_RUNTIME
               Stubs=0x3:FACILITY_STUBS
               Io=0x4:FACILITY_IO_ERROR_CODE
              )
   LanguageNames=(English=0x409:MSG00409)
; // The following are the categories of events.
   MessageIdTypedef=WORD
   MessageId=0x1
   SymbolicName=NETWORK_CATEGORY
   Language=English
   Network Events
   ... rest of file omitted
```

The .mc file is compiled into a .res file which is linked into a .dll:

To compile the message text file, use the following command:

```
 mc -U provider.mc
```

To compile the resources that the message compiler generated, use the following command:

```
rc provider.rc
```

To create the resource-only DLL that contains the message table string resources, use the following command (you can run the command from a Visual Studio Command Prompt):

```
   link -dll -noentry provider.res
```

...